# Android facebook SDK - unable to set onclicklistener for facebook sharebutton

Tags: android, facebook

I wanted to create a FB share button in android app. My minimum sdk is 16.

in my gradle file i have the following dependency:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
```

The issue is when i set an onClicklistener on the facebook share button its not responding (i even used a breakpoint to make sure).  It never hits the callback and the button is greyed out. Here are my settings on facebook for this app:

[image]

Please note HERE I AM USING THE DEBUG KEY HASH.  So everything im doing is not in release but in debug signature.

In the android manifest i have the following defined inside the application tag:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="123456789"/>


<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider123456789"
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:exported="true" />
```

To initialize the facebook sdk i have my own subclass of application (recorded in manifest application tag) which works fine & my break points get it:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);
}
```

}

the application builds and runs fine except for the facebook button. in a layout file i declared  a facebook share button like this:

```
<com.facebook.share.widget.ShareButton
    android:id="@+id/fb_share_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/share_fb"
    />
```

Then in my activity class im gaining a reference to this view in onCreate by the following:

```
mShareButton = (ShareButton)findViewById(R.id.fb_share_button);
mShareButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and my activity implements the onClickListener and all thats in that is a log statement which NEVER gets printed and break points dont hit there. What else do i need to do here. I am running off a lolipop device and i am logged into the facebook app on my phone. I dont know if this is needed but i also created the callbackManager in my activity oncreate method like this:

```
mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
```

and the debug hash was created successfully with the following command:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

My end goal is that when user clicks the facebookshare button i will run the following code to share something to facebook:

```
if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
            ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                    .setContentTitle("Hello Facebook")
                    .setContentDescription(
                            "The 'Hello Facebook' sample  showcases simple Facebook integration")
                    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://developers.facebook.com/android"))
                    .build();

            mShareDialog.show(linkContent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a day of frustration i figured out the issue.

in the android manifest i had defined the FB app ID directly as a string. I was trying to be quick about it for testing so i just used a raw string like "12345667" as the value in the meta-data.  Instead you have to use a string value as per below, issue resolved.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/fb_app_id"/>
```

note: you dont need to set a onclicklistener for the share button. just sent its content like this:

```
ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.facebook.com"))
            .build();

    mShareButton.setShareContent(content);
```